# Issue with Rotation in 4-Bar Chain Mechanism in Blender

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I am currently working on a 4-bar chain mechanism in Blender and have encountered an issue with the rotation of the bones. Here's the setup:

1. I started by adding a series of bones, with the last bone being named Bone.004. The first bone (Bone) serves as the fixed link in the chain.
2. I set Bone.004 to be the child of the first bone (Bone) in the chain. In other words, Bone is the parent of Bone.004.
3. I applied an IK (Inverse Kinematics) constraint to the Bone.003 to Bone.004 connection. However, when I rotate the active bone (Bone.003), I expect to see two cranks rotating 360 degrees each.
4. The problem I am facing is that the bones are not rotating as expected. Instead of the two cranks rotating 360 degrees, the bones seem to be rotating individually around themselves.

I believe this issue might be related to the length and fixed nature of the first bone, causing a disruption in the intended rotation. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem and achieve the desired rotation of the bones in my 4-bar chain mechanism.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Attachement: https://i.imgur.com/aG1lPNE.gif

Update: I Selected Bone.004 and ensured that it is not parented to any other bone.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Hello Ramos,

Thank you for your response. I appreciate your guidance. As a newbie, I apologize for not using the built-in tools to embed images in my post. I will make sure to follow the instructions you provided in the future. Your support is invaluable as I continue my learning journey with Blender.

Best regards,
Arif.

Comment: You have a fixed bone and a control bone.  Just use a 2-chain IK for the other two bones in the 4-bar.  Lock all but a single axis on both of those bones.  In 4.0.1, this works fine, giving you a full 360 degrees rotation on your crank bones.